# Is it OK if I sign Android debug and production builds with the same key?

Tags: android, android-signing

I ran into SHA-1 messed-up situation (I guess) with firebase config. So, I decided to sign both debug and and production builds with the same key (my own key, not the default debug key). Will that cause any problem in the future? 
tks

Comment: You can add more than one SHA-1 key in firebase

Answer (score 0):

It's ok. As long as you keep this key not publicly available. Easiest way is to assign signing config to both debug, and release profile in build.gradle